# Compilation error in format function

Tags: c#

What is the problem with this code. I am unable to understand.

```
string myString = string.Format("{2} - {3}", "3", "4", "5");
```

Comment: Index start at zero, {3} means, get the 4th parameter, but there aren't 4 parameters

Comment: Wow, for a question from a first time user, this question really isn't all that bad.  I don't think it deserves all these down votes.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - The title of the question starts with "Compiliation error" but the OP did not include the error in question forcing the reader to try to deduce what the problem is.  In this case it is fairly simple, but the question is a poor question.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in too many parameters.  And your indices need to start from zero, but instead you start from two.

```
string.Format("{0}-{1}", "3", "4")
```

will print:

```
3-4
```

String.Format takes "how you want to display your text", and some values that you want to substitute into it.  There's actually nothing wrong with you passing in additional print variables, they just won't print:

```
String.Format("{0}-{0}", "3", "2", "5", 
"10000")
```

will print:

```
3-3
```

And see, I've told it to print the zero-th indexed parameter twice.